# Remove duplicate entries in database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 code first . I am working on a product in which the release version of the product there there are duplicate entries in a **UserName** column in the **UserProfile** table. To remove this bug I am using the Index annotation on the UserName field.

```
class UserProfile
{
     [Index("IX",IsUnique=True)]
     string UserName;
     string Id;
 }
```

so that now the duplicate entry problem goes away. But I dont have backward compatibility now. As in the customers who are already using the release product and have duplicate entries in their database cannot use their existing database.

I have created a migration using entity framework and it updates the database like this

```
public partial class UserConcurrencyFix : DbMigration
{
     public override void Up()
     {
          CreateIndex("dbo.UserProfiles", "UserName", unique: true);
     }
     public override void Down()
     {
          DropIndex("dbo.UserProfiles", new[] { "UserName" });
     }
 }
```

This does not take care of existing databases that already have duplicate entries. Is there a way I can remove duplicates from databases that already being used by the users and have duplicate entries?

Comment: Can you actually automate this deduplication without data loss? Shouldn't the users take care of that, following their own procedure, before they upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Up migration method, before the index is added. Execute a script using the Sql() method. This can be any script you want, so just create one that does the desired deduplication and you're all set.